# What to use to crimp a resistor onto 18awg wire

Tags: resistors, connector, crimp

I want to crimp a resistor like the one below onto 18awg wire without soldering...

[image]

I've seen that bootlace ferrules like the photo below can possibly be used to do this but if I buy 22-24awg sized bootlace ferrules then the 18awg wire won't fit. And if I buy 18awg sized bootlace ferrules I'm concerned it won't properly crimp the resistor in place.

[image]

What is the best solution to achieve a connection between the resistor and 18awg wire without soldering them together?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A ferrule is NOT a reliable or permanent crimp device for your application.  The metal walls are far too thin.

Try it: crimp two resistors in a ferrule.  Bend them at right-angles to each other and try to spin them inside the ferrule.  You will find that they spin quite freely.

What DOES work reliably is the barrel from a standard non-insulated crimp terminal.  Find a crimp terminal that both wire fit inside and cut the terminal portion away from the barrel.  Put both wires inside the barrel and crimp with a proper crimp tool.

This makes a permanent, gas-tight connection that will last for decades.

FWIW - my preferred crimp style for non-insulated barrels of this type is known as a "W" crimp - so-called because of the "W" shape left in the barrel after crimping.  The AMP Certi-Lok tool with the "W" crimp die-set is one popular choice.

Almost as good is the T&B "StaKon" crimp tool that electricians use - the small crimp nest works well for barrels up to 16 AWG, the large crimp nest works up to 10 AWG.

Finally, if you don't have any non-insulated crimp terminals handy, just remove the plastic insulation from insulated terminals.  The barrel is pretty much exactly the same as the non-insulated terminal.

Answer (score 0):

If you overlap the resistor lead and the #18 wire in a ferrule for #18 wire (or slightly larger) or insert both from the same end, you should get a good connection.  If you put the #18 wire part way in the ferrule, and the resistor part way in from the other end, it probably won't work.

Comment: Have you personally tried that and it worked? I'm concerned that even with the overlap, because the 18awg wire is stranded and the resistor is solid that it may be able to slide out relatively easily still

Comment: If the ferrule is properly crimped, I don't think it would be possible to pull the resistor lead out (but I haven't tried it...)

Comment: @Matt Bootlace ferrules are NOT a crimp connector - they keep strands together when used with a screw or cage joiner to prevent strand damage and current hogging.

Comment: I'd categorize ferrules as crimps. Termination ferrule crimps are a type of crimp contact.